# Calendar Control Event Issues in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, calendar

I'm trying to bind a TextBox to the selected date on a Calendar control, and when it initializes, there is no issue.  The problem is that after, when I change the selected date, the TextBox remains at its initial value (today).  I have tried 3 methods, including simply returning to TextBox.Text = Calendar.DisplayDate.ToString(), but the problem persists.

Does anybody know either what causes this, or a way around it?

Note that PropertyChanged is not null in Method 2.

My code is as follows, with the other two methods implemented:

XAML:

```
<Calendar Grid.Column="1" Height="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="calStart" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="180" IsTodayHighlighted="False" SelectedDatesChanged="CalStartSelectedDatesChanged">
            <Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource conv}}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="LightGreen" />

                        </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
     </Calendar>
 <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,33,0,0" Text="{Binding StartBindProp, Mode=OneWay}" Name="txtStartDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
```

C#
Method 1:

```
private void CalStartSelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartBindProp = calStart.DisplayDate.ToString();
    }


    public string StartBindProp
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StartBindPropProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartBindPropProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StartBindProp.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartBindPropProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StartBindProp", typeof(string), typeof(MainControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

Method 2:

```
 private void CalEndSelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EndBind = calEnd.DisplayDate.ToString();
    }

    private string m_EndBind = "endtest";


    public string EndBind
    {
        get { return m_EndBind; }
        set
        {
            m_EndBind = value;

            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("EndBind"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
The following xaml has the same issue (and apparently renders the calendar read-only):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=calStart, Path=DisplayDate, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Calendar.SelectedDate` (or `SelectedDates` if multiple) instead of `DisplayDate`

I believe the `DisplayDate` is used to determine which date has the "selected" outline around it in the calendar (since multiple dates can be selected), while `SelectedDate` is the actual value of the control.

You can find the MSDN docs on the Calendar control [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.aspx)

Comment: Display date should work fine- it certainly works well enough on the initial binding, but that is an entirely different discussion.  Using SelectedDate (.Value) renders the same result.
Also, I have checked the MSDN docs, as well as checking through the source code for the calendar, and it has proved unhelpful thus far.

Comment: @SeanVDH Just double-checked your code. If you put a breakpoint in your `set` method for `StartBind`, does the value get set when the date changes? And is `PropertyChanged == null`?

Comment: First thing- thanks for pointing that out, that snippet should not have been part of StartBind, but it is identical to the second.

Yes the value is changed, and `PropertyChanged != null`

Comment: @SeanVDH Just copy/pasted the code you posted in your question and it works fine providing I replace `DisplayDate` with `SelectedDate` in your `CalStartSelectedDatesChanged`

Comment: *You were correct, I had something left over from a previous answer, which was interfering with this process.  Thanks for the help!