# How to keep all date selection in calendar?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a code that read dates from a database and put them into the Calendar control. All working good, but if the user select a date in the Calendar, after the population, all the date selected through code disappear. There's another way to flag the date that are previously added from the database population?

```
public void setFixturesControl()
{
        Database.m_dbConnection.Open();
        string query = "select * from date";
        SQLiteCommand input = new SQLiteCommand(query, Database.m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = input.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read()) 
        {
            if (MainWindow.AppWindow.League.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals(reader["caption"].ToString()))
            {
                MainWindow.AppWindow.Calendar.SelectedDates.Add(DateTime.Parse(reader["data"].ToString()));
            }
        }
        Database.m_dbConnection.Close();
    }
```

There's a way to prevent the dates disappear after a user click? Or something that allow me to recognize the dates added by database population? Thanks.

Comment: This is just an idea, but how about you create a delegate event to be triggered everytime you change the [displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7811528/1257607) date in the calendar, in the method you can apply any validations, changes required.

Comment: there's nothing available in the control to keep the dates, actually?

Comment: Actually I don't think so, take a look at [Calendar class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.aspx)

Comment: I hope for a solution, currently I have not found anything on the net.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search on the net and a large documentation on the Calendar class, I could see two things:

1. To get what I want I have to take advantage of a custom control
2. Try to act via code by creating a delegate, but this is not really a
   simple thing

I ran then in the first point, in particular, from the [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104081/Extending-the-WPF-Calendar-Control) of David Veeneman, it addresses exactly my problem.
The final result will be like this:

[image]

Exactly what I want.

In the post it is all documented, so it would be pointless to do a copy paste here. Thank this member that for me at least was able to solve a failure in the control of Microsoft. Unfortunately I am increasingly convinced that WPF is still immature and that still requires a bit 'of years to complete. I hope my answer is help, if anyone manages to solve the problem in a more elegant, well it responds well. Thank You.